# `git ls-files` includes unmerged files thrice

Tags: git, git-ls-files

For example:

```
$ git status
On branch master
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
  (use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

    both modified:   test.txt
```

```
$ git ls-files
test.txt
test.txt
test.txt
```

Is there any way to make it list files of this kind only once too? I only need the file names.

Comment: Consider using `git status --porcelain` or `git status --porcelain=v2` for machine-readable output. Or, use `git ls-files --stage` and parse the full output.

Comment: Good suggestion, but `git status` does not support all the options I need. In particular, there's no way to include the unmodified files in the output.

Answer (score 2):

That happens when there is a conflict. Each one of them is a different version of the file. Check with:

```
git ls-files -s
```

Take a look at `git help read-tree`, the section about **3-way merge**. The important part for you is this: `...and you will end up with an index with all of the <tree1> entries in "stage1", all of the <tree2> entries in "stage2" and all of the <tree3> entries in "stage3". When performing a merge of another branch into the current branch, we use the common ancestor tree as <tree1>, the current branch head as <tree2>, and the other branch head as <tree3>`

Comment: Yes, the question is about conflicted files.

Comment: This answer is good, but adds nothing new to me personally. Have an upvote, though. And thanks.

Comment: If you want to see them only once, you might use tools outside of git for that: `git ls-files | uniq`. Pehaps keep it as a (bash) alias?

Comment: I'm using it in a script. Oh well, `uniq` is pretty good, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to make it list files of this kind only once too?

```
git ls-files | sort -u
```

Git tends not to duplicate existing tools.